# Run a PHP file in a cron job using Control Panel

Tags: php

I am  trying to run a PHP script using a cron job within CPanel - is this the correct syntax:
/home/username/public_html/cron.php

But i dont get mail from my file cron.php,i  gave every 5 minue option.

Code in cron.php

```
<?php
$to  = 'test@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Whole Sale VoIP Provider';
$message = "Name"; 
$content='test@test.com/';
$Headers = "From:$content\r\n" . 
"Reply-To: $content \r\n" . 
"Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 \r\n"; 
$Headers.= "MIME-version: 1.0\n";
$mail=mail($to,$subject, $message, $Headers);
?>
```

Comment: after setting day and time, write in command like  `/home/servername/public_html/www.hostname.com/application_directory/cron_file_name.php`

Comment: Does the script run independent?

Comment: @DarkBee, YES, after setting cronjob your script run independently after each interval of time which you set.

Comment: added the code in cron.php,please check it

Comment: I mean did u test the script in a browser before trying to run it as cron?

Comment: @DarkBEE  Yes i tested,it is working

Comment: @SHAZ i gave these comment  /home/servername/public_html/http://hostname.com/cron.php ,,,but it is not working

Comment: @shilnamk, Sorry i cant edit my above answer. 
Now try to use below one, It working definitely...
     `/usr/bin/php -q /home/servername/public_html/www.hostname.com/application_directory/cron_file_n‌​ame.php `


Note: There is space after -q, not newline

Comment: I think you need to add the php command as well, I tested It on ubuntu VPS and it worked for me I did it like:
#* * * * *  /user/bin/php5 /var/www/sendmail.php >> /var/www/file.log
I think It should work.

Comment: @SHAZ 
/usr/bin/php -q /home/servername/public_html/http://test.com/cron.php    I gave these ,but not working

Comment: which hosting you are using and can you briefly explain how you do that cron task setup in your hosting?
B'coz my cron file working perfectly on my hosting.

Comment: @SHAZ In your code you used  www.hostname.com  instead of it i used  http://servername.com

Comment: I think you should show your crontab code as well.

Answer (score 1):

You should try the following, Defiantly It will work for you:

Your crontab   should be like this:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
HOME=/
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/senmail.php >> /var/www/log.txt
```

It will execute your php file every minute.And you should also try running your file in browser.